# Is it a good practice to start intent in adapter in MVVM?

Tags: android, android-intent, mvvm

I'm creating an Android app according to MVVM pattern and I'm not sure if I should start intent from adapter. In adapter I'm creating Intent that has to open given uri in browser after user taps one. Technically it all works but I'm still not sure if it is a good practice to start intent like that, instead of starting it from activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good practice. Your view (meaning your `Fragment` or `Activity`) should be handling the navigation. Instead, the accepted way is to pass a `clickListener` from your view into your adapter when you instantiate the adapter. This is covered in various articles, [so pick the one you like best](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20pass%20click%20listener%20to%20adapter&oq=android%20pass%20click%20listener%20to%20adapter&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30l2.5086j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Or you can take a look at my implementation [here](https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games/blob/adc8b7e67b1e05d7bc9ac6247b82cfa93a43a26f/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/upcominggames/ui/list/ListFragment.kt#L31) and [here](https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/upcominggames/ui/list/GameGridAdapter.kt).

It's also covered in [this excellent free Udacity course](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012).